# Почему preg_replace не обрабатывает шаблон?

Tags: php

```
$document = "<html><head></head><body><b>Hi</b><?php echo \"lol\";?><br></body></head></html>";
function shighlight($document)
{
    // Преобразуем угловые скобки для отображения HTML-тегов
    $document = str_replace("<", "&lt", $document);
    $document = str_replace(">", "&gt", $document);
    // Преобразуем теги PHP <?php и ? >
    $tegs = array("'&lt;\?php'i","'&lt;\?'i","'\?&gt;'i");
    $replace = array(
        "<font color=#95001E>&lt;?php</font>",
        "<font color=#95001E>&lt;?</font>",
        "<font color=#95001E>?&gt;</font>",);
    $document = preg_replace($tegs, $replace, $document);
    echo($document);
}
shighlight($document);
```

Никак не могу понять, почему не обрабатывает шаблон, ошибок не выдаёт.

Comment: Тут нет телепатов. Что конкретно неправильно работает?

Comment: В обоих str_replace нужно добавить точку с запятой в замену.

Comment: я не понимаю, что вы хотите добиться, но может htmlentities($document) будет проще?

Comment: str_replace работает как надо, дело в том, что не обрабатывается строка по шаблону. В итоге на выводе мы получаем строку без подсветки синтаксиса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В замене `str_replace` нет `;`, а в регулярке `preg_replace` проверка на этот символ.

Должно быть так:

```
$document = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $document);
$document = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $document);
```